# Getting model attributes from belongs_to on scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have a `Person` model and a `Book`. A person belongs_to a book.

I have this scope defined in my `Book` model:

```
belongs_to :person

scope :by_title, ->(title) do 
 fake_query.where(title: title)
end
```

Now when I use this scope,

```
@person = Person.first
@person.todays_books.by_title('test-123').first
```

Basically how do I gain access to the `@person` attributes within the actual scope so I can do something like this:

```
scope :by_title, ->(title) do
 fake_query.where(title: title, person_id: @person)
end
```

I know I could pass it as an argument e.g. `->(title, @person)` but I know there is probably a better way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: you don't need it, you're already joining `person` with this `@person.todays_books.by_title`

Answer (score 0):

you are already looking for books that belongs to that person when you chain @person.todays_books, so what you are trying to do isn't necessary